# Distinct count of rows using a join in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to get a distinct count of Enquiries with Food and Drink in Power Bi. The way the database is structured is:

1 Enquiry could have multiple days, which have food and drink attached to them.
I want to try and calculate how many enquiries have food and drink attached so I need to do a distinct count on the enquiry id in the Enquiries table where a record exists in the **food and drink table**

The table structure is as follows:

Enquiry Table

```
EnquiryId
10
```

Enquiry Day Table

```
EnquiryDayID     EnquiryId
5                10
6                10
```

Enquiry Day Food Drink Table

```
EnquiryDayFoodDrinkId      EnquiryDayId
20                         5
21                         6
```

Basically I want the distinct count to only return 1 as there is only one distinct enquiry with food + Drink attached.

Here is the code in SQL which return the correct number. I want to get the same result in Power BI

```
select count (distinct(e.pkEnquiries))
from EnquiryDayFoodDrink edfd
inner join EnquiryDay ed
on ed.EnquiryDayId = edfd.EnquiryDayId
inner join Enquiries e
on ed.EnquiryId = e.pkEnquiries
```

Comment: `ed.EnquiryDayId = edfd.EnquiryDayFoodDrinkId` not `ed.EnquiryDayId = edfd.EnquiryDayId`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson yes you are correct, was a typo, fixing now